# Помогите найти ошибку с подзапросом SQL

Tags: sql

Определить, сколько потратил в 2005 году каждый из членов семьи
Поля в результирующей таблице:
member_name
status
costs
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мое решение:

```
SELECT member_name,
       status,
       ( SELECT SUM(amount * unit_price)
         FROM Payments
         WHERE family_member = FamilyMembers.member_id
           AND YEAR(date) = 2005 ) AS costs
FROM FamilyMembers
GROUP BY member_name,
         status
```

Comment: А с чего ты решил, что там ошибка?

Comment: Подсвечивается "неверный ответ' и вот это: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'family.FamilyMembers.member_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: подразумевается обычно, группировка это когда агрегатная функция и группировка пишутся в одном и том же запросе, а не подзапросах. В данном случае тут группировка просто избыточна

Comment: можно переписать и с группировкой, но подзапрос надо заменить на джйон. либо то либо то

Comment: Понял , спасибо

Comment: Да удалить GROUP BY вообще - он в этом запросе лишний. А подзапрос как раз нормальный.

Comment: Это вообще в один запрос через join надо бы делдать.

Comment: Я специально хотел с подзапросом, тем и тем способом.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь можно обойтись без подзапроса и JOIN, если не хотите дважды группировать в основном запросе и подзапросе:

```
SELECT member_name,
       status,
       SUM(amount * unit_price) AS costs
FROM Payments, FamilyMembers
WHERE family_member = FamilyMembers.member_id
      AND YEAR(date) = 2005
GROUP BY member_name,
         status
```